# Connecting to DB2 works from Delphi XE8 but executable fails with an ODBC error

Tags: delphi, db2, odbc, delphi-xe8

I'm trying to connect to a DB2 LUW 10.5 database. This works perfectly from the Delphi XE8 environment but if I'm connecting using the compiled executable, I get the error below. What am I missing here?

> Exception EDB2NativeException in module [FireDac][Phys][ODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on sql_handle_env failed.

Comment: When you say "works perfectly from the Delphi XE8 environment" do you mean you can connect to the DB by setting some connection component's properties in the IDE?  If so, and the same operation fails at run-time, possibly the difference is related to the location of the compiled executable and/or the values in the (OS) Environment variables it sees at r/time.  Oh, and what is your compilation target, Win32, Win64 or what?  Please add the compilation target to your q.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I originally compiled a Win32 target. After your answer I compiled to a Win64 target en that worked in XE and at runtime. The 32bits version isn't working.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like your app maybe isn't finding the right driver dll(s) from the directory it is being compiled to.  Probably, you should inspect the PATH in the environment your 32-bit version will run in and check that it will be able to find them.  Of course, the XE8 IDE and the packages it loads are 32-bit, and if you can connect in the IDE, there must presumably be something different viewed from the directory the compiled app runs in.